# New fonts in command prompt appearing in Default settings but not in Properties

Tags: cmd.exe

I added some fonts to my command prompt by adding them to the registry. These fonts seem to appear when I edit the Default font settings but they do not appear when I edit the Properties font settings. The Default font settings also do not apply when I open in a new window. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have done something wrong. In order to have a custom font you need to create a key and then write a unique number for the value *(I wrote **000** in my case)*. After that write your custom font in the Value Data. Click **OK** to apply them then reboot. After the reboot run **cmd.exe** right click on the title navigate to **Properties** then  navigate to **Font**. Select the custom font and boom. We're done!